# count the occurrence of each element in an array not in sorting order the order will be as it is asked in question

Tags: java

I am trying to count the frequencies of every element in array. But one constraints is there that is I don't want to print the element in sorting order.

My input is like

```
7 1 2 1 1 6 8 7
```

and output is coming in this format
    {1=3, 2=1, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1}

which I don't want

my output should be like

```
7 2 

1 3 

2 1

6 1

8 1
```

for given above input. And I don't want any delimiter

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n],temp=0,count=0,flag=-1,b[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        Map<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap();

        for(int x:a){
            if(!hm.containsKey(x)){
                hm.put(x,1);
            }else{
                hm.put(x, hm.get(x)+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly. It's really hard to read it like this.

Comment: Use Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new LinkedHashMap<>(); instead of HashMap to keep insertion-order.

Comment: thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LinkedHashMap` to maintain insertion order. Then use

```
hm.entrySet().forEach(e ->  System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

rather than just printing the map, iterate over it and print each key and value.

Comment: thanks for your beautiful answer but i am still getting the output in sorted order which i don't want please see my required output

Comment: Are you using a LinkedHashMap? Declare your array like `Map<Integer,Integer> hm = new LinkedHashMap();` It worked for me!

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 : I'd really appreciate it, if you accept my answer.

Comment: sorry but i can't because of less reputation..but i am accepting it from my heart :)

Comment: Nothing like that, all you need to do is to click the green tick next to the vote button.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want random order or a sort order, then you should be able to use a `LinkedHashMap` which will give you insert-order iteration when it's time to print.  At that point, @Nicholas K's solution for print formatting works well.

Comment: that solution now includes the LinkedHashMap...so it's good all by itself

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative if you continue to use `HashMap`

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = hm.entrySet().iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.next(); 
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```